# Powershell sync script attempting to overwrite source files instead of copying to the destination

Tags: linux-mint, powershell-core

This script is attempting to overwrite the source files rather than copying to the destination, and I'm not sure why. Prior to updating Powershell Core to 6.1, it functioned as intended. The script is intended to sync the music directory without including the folders.

```
if (Test-Path /fileserver/MP3playerMusic)
{
    $sourcefiles = Get-ChildItem /fileserver/MP3PlayerMusic -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Extension -ne ".dat"} 
    $destinationfiles = Get-ChildItem /home/username/Music -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Extension -ne ".dat" } 
    $destinationdirectories = "/home/username/Music"
    $filedifferenceobject = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourcefiles -DifferenceObject $destinationfiles
    $filedifferenceobject | foreach { $copyparams = @{'path' = $_.inputobject.fullname} 
    if ( $filedifferenceobject.sideindicator -eq '<=' )
                { "files are not synced"
              "Syncing files"
              $copyparams.Destination = $destinationdirectories
              Copy-Item @copyparams -Verbose
             }
        else
        { "files are synced" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try posting on github.com/powershell/powershell - this might be a compatibility bug, especially if it worked on ps 5

Comment: I need to figure out where the issue is, then.

Comment: Change the line `if ( $filedifferenceobject.sideindicator -eq '<=' )` in `if ( $_.sideindicator -eq '<=' )`. The original statement almost always evaluates to true, because it is true is **any** of the sideindicators in the whole collection is <=.  I tested in PS 5.1 and 6.1 and observed the same difference in error messages as you have. First of all your script logic I needs to be fixed IMHO

Comment: While that eliminates the basic error about overwriting the source files, it's still attempting to copy files that already exist in the destination.